I am unable to send data through $http.get service in angularjs to a php file
I'm testing out a function before integrating it into my project. Basically, a button press should push an object into an array and then send that array to another php file. So, I've created a basic file sending data through the get method, I even get a response alert saying the data received is xyz. But when i open the php file, I get an error saying undefined key "cart" in php file. Here are the codes:
Main file(test.php):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="testapp" ng-controller="testctrl">
    <button ng-click="senddata()">Send</button>
    <a href="http://localhost/proj/process_cart.php">Click</a>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("testapp", []);
        app.controller("testctrl", function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.cart = [];
            $scope.senddata = function() {
                $scope.cart.push({id: 1, name: "Aaryan"});
                var url = "http://localhost/proj/process_cart.php";
                var data = { cart: JSON.stringify($scope.cart) }; // Send data as a string
                $http.get(url, { params: data })
                .then(function(response) {
                    alert(response.data);
                }, function(error) {
                    alert('Error: ' + error.data);
                });
            };
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>


and here is the process_order.php file:
<?php
$cart = json_decode($_GET['cart'], true);

if ($cart) {
    echo "Received cart data:\n";
    print_r($cart);
} else {
    echo "Error: No cart data received.";
}
?>


What can i do to fix this?
I expected the value of the cart to be printed but I actually got an error saying the error key is undefined. help please

By "open" do you mean request the file with your browser without a GET request? Loading http://localhost/proj/process_cart.php doesn't have a parameter named cart so $_GET['cart'] is accessing an unavailable index. Use isset or !empty as all these cases are solved with.... or test with http://localhost/proj/process_cart.php?cart=someJSON

Why don't you use $_POST to send data?

Does this answer your question? "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP

@user3783243 yes, that's what i meant. And i get it now, I get a response saying "data received:xyz" so the data is being passed and ready to process, but when I click on the link, there is no get request made. I am however stuck as i want to access and use the data in the other file

@Justinas for some reason while using post i get an error in the console saying "cannot read properties of undefined(reading post)" (yes, i injected the $http service)

@user3783243 the post is helpful but im still lost

@user3783243 your method worked! i tried including the http://localhost/proj/process_cart.php?cart=someJSON method and it worked! Thank you so much for your help!

@AaryanFatnani From the duplicate post you should get that isset or !empty should be used on variables that may not always be set. This will test the condition before using it an not emit an error when it is encountered. So for your script you could do https://3v4l.org/Jaa7u Might want to change conditional to if (!empty($_GET['cart']) && json_decode($_GET['cart'], true)){ also to ensure you have valid JSON data coming in.

"i tried including the localhost/proj/process_cart.php?cart=someJSON method and it worked!" - even if that "worked", it is really rather bad practice IMHO, to make a system make an HTTP request to itself in such a situation. If you want to go to /proj/process_cart.php to begin with - then why are you making a background request here in the first place? Make your JS append the parameter directly to the href of the link, and then let the link click proceed as normal ...
